# Export Jquery bootgrid to Excel

Tags: c#, gridview, export-to-excel, jquery-bootgrid

I am using Jquery boot grid with asp.net gridview as follows.

```
$(function () {
           $('#<%= MyGridview.ClientID %>').bootgrid({
               caseSensitive: false
           });
       });
```

When i filter the grid using the Search provided by boot grid, i would like to export the filtered rows to Excel. Is there a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest spreadsheet format to export to is CSV - and that's entirely a backend thing.

```
$("#grid-id").bootgrid("getSearchPhrase");
```

will get you the search criteria to help build the request for the CSV. See http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation#properties for other options.